# filter metadata inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

In my fiddle below I cannot figure out how to filter the metadata. The metadata needs to be reduced so that it looks like the final JSON shown below.
The final JSON object should be like shown below (The JSON object is two companies since Ford was not present in the fav array and the metadata for Honda and Toyota is reduced). How can I achieve this https://jsfiddle.net/netchi/rb2oLq1w/25/ 
I am open to re arranging the way metadata array is defined if need be.

```
  {
    text: "Toyota",
    origin: "Japan",
    icon: "icon",
    metaData: [
      {
        text: "Sedans",
        models: "4"
      }
    ]
  }, 
  {
    text: "Honda",
    models: "8",
    icon: "icon",
    metaData: [
      {
        text: "Suvs",
        models: "4"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: (The desired output isn’t valid JSON)

Comment: Please put all relevant code into the question. Not behind a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions. One Assuming, all metadata will have matching sub-menu. Other assuming, there may case not having sub-menu matching. Then exclude that company.

```js
var fav = ["Toyota", "Honda"];
var ToyotaMetadata = ["Sedans"];
var HondaMetadata = ["Suvs"];
const favMap = {
    Toyota: ["Sedans"],
    Honda: ["Suvs"]
};
var companies = [
    {
        text: "Toyota",
        origin: "Japan",
        icon: "icon",
        metaData: [
            {
                text: "Suvs",
                models: "4"
            },
            {
                text: "Sedans",
                models: "4"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        text: "Ford",
        founder: "Henry Ford",
        icon: "icon"
    },

    {
        text: "Honda",
        models: "8",
        icon: "icon",
        metaData: [
            {
                text: "Suvs",
                models: "4"
            },
            {
                text: "Sedans",
                models: "4"
            }
        ]
    }
];
const merge = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return Object.assign.apply({}, args)
}
// Simple
const res2 = companies.reduce((map, comp) => {
    if (favMap[comp.text]) {
        map.push(merge(comp, { metaData: comp.metaData.filter(x => favMap[comp.text].indexOf(x.text) != -1) }));
    }
    return map;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res2, null, 4));

// Above will fail. if company is without metadata of car model, still match fav
/*
{
    text: "Toyota",
    origin: "Japan",
    icon: "icon",
    metaData: [
    ]
  },
*/

// Complex
const res = companies.reduce((map, comp) => {
    let index = 0;
    if (
        favMap[comp.text] &&
        comp.metaData.some(x => {
            index++;
            if (favMap[comp.text].indexOf(x.text) != -1) {
                return true;
            }
        })
    ) {
        map.push(merge(comp, { metaData: [comp.metaData[index - 1]] }));
    }
    return map;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

Comment: for the simple way, can you show me how to achieve map.push without using the spread operator (...comp)? I need to use it in IE and it's not compatible @xdeepakv

Comment: i have updated solution. U can use `merge` util function. 
`const merge = function () {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return Object.assign.apply({}, args)
}`

Comment: I have update! if it helped you. Accept as answer! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can define your settings as an object and the use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for outer array and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the inner one:

```
let metadataConf = { "Toyota": ToyotaMetadata, "Honda": HondaMetadata };

let result = companies.filter(x => x.metaData).map(({metaData, text, ...fields}) => ({ 
     ...fields, text, metaData: metaData.filter(x => metadataConf[text].includes(x.text)) 
}));
```

```js
var fav = ["Toyota", "Honda"];
var ToyotaMetadata = ["Sedans"];
var HondaMetadata = ["Suvs"]

var companies = [
  {
    text: "Toyota",
    origin: "Japan",
    icon: "icon",
    metaData: [
      {
        text: "Suvs",
        models: "4"
      },
      {
        text: "Sedans",
        models: "4"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    text: "Ford",
    founder: "Henry Ford",
    icon: "icon"
  },
  
  {
    text: "Honda",
    models: "8",
    icon: "icon",
    metaData: [
      {
        text: "Suvs",
        models: "4"
      },
      {
        text: "Sedans",
        models: "4"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let metadataConf = { "Toyota": ToyotaMetadata, "Honda": HondaMetadata };

let result = companies.filter(x => x.metaData).map(({metaData, text, ...rest}) => ({ ...rest, text, metaData: metaData.filter(x => metadataConf[text].includes(x.text)) 
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can be optimize using reduce. one less looping!!